# Why are there so many different definitions for differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition

I am studying differentiability for functions of several variables.

Here is the first definition of differentiability I came across:$\quad$
A function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a\in\Bbb R^n$ if there is a linear transformation $\lambda:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left|\,f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\,\right|}{\left|\,h\,\right|}=0.$$
Next I found this other definition:$\quad$A function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a\in\Bbb R^n$ if there is a linear transformation $\lambda:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)}{\left|\,h\,\right|}=0.$$
Finally I found the following one:$\quad$ A function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a\in\Bbb R^n$ if there is a linear transformation $\lambda:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ and a function $r:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ such that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\,\,r(h)=0$ and $$f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)=\left|\,h\right|\,r(h)$$

Are all these definitions equivalent?  Why are there so many definitions for a single concept?  What are the advantages of one definition over the others?

Comment: yes, they are all equivalent - some functions can only be differentiated using a specific definition

Comment: In the second definition be careful with the notafion since the numerator is a vector, then I suppose you mean that the limit is $\vec{0}$, i.e. the 0 vector.

Comment: They are hardly different, they express the same "difference is sublinear" idea in slightly different language. Yes, they are equivalent. In this case they are too similar to discuss possible advantages, but in general, different equivalent definitions emphasise different aspect of given property, possibly giving different insights. On the practical side, some definitions make properties easier to prove than others - part of "hardness" is delegated to the proof of equivalence of definitions.

Comment: @Martingalo Yes, with 0 I mean both the real number 0 and the zero vectors.

Comment: Fine. Then the equivalence between def. 1 and 2 is immediate since the euclidean norm $|\cdot|$ is a norm and it is continuous.

Comment: @Martingalo You're right: the first is the norm of the second, so they are equivalent.  But does equality hold for all continuous functions, or only for the norm? I mean the following: suppose we have a function $g$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} g(x)= 0$ and a function $f$ continuous at 0 and such that $f(0)=0$ (like the norm in our case). Then, is it true that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(g(x)) = 0$?

Comment: In definition 3, I don't think you meant to include the limit on the left side.

Comment: @Matteo Yes. By definition of continuity: in a neighbourhood of 0, any sequence $x_n \to 0$ then $f(x_n)\to f(0)$.
I agree with Nate Eldredge by the way :)

Comment: @Martingalo Sorry, I wrote the contrary of what I wanted. The question is: suppose we have a function $f$ defined as above (continuous at 0 and such that $f(0) = 0$) and a function $g$; if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(g(x)) = 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$?
This is equivalent to ask if $g$ necessarily has a limit (because, if so, then it must be 0)

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Yes, sorry :) But I just copied and pasted for laziness

Comment: @Mateo no. Counterexample: $f(x) = x(1-x)$ and $g(x)=x+1$ then $f(g(x)) = -(x+1)x$ then we have $\lim_{x\to 0} f(g(x))=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 1$.

Comment: @Martingalo Ok.  Instead, for the norm does it hold?  Because you used it (I think) to show that the first definition implies the second

Comment: To see the equivalence just write: $0 = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|A_h|}{|h|} = |\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{A_h}{|h|}|$ where I can put the limit inside since $x \mapsto |x|$ is continuous. It's as simple as that. (Here $A_h$ means the whole numerator) Ah! and remember that for a norm $|x|=0 \iff x=0$.

Comment: @Martingalo Let's change a bit: let $f$ be continuous such that $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.  If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(g(x)) = 0$, then is it necessarily true that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ exists? (and if it exists it has to be 0).

Comment: @Matteo Haha! you are twisting things around just to get the statement to work :) Yes. Precisely, you define $f$ satisfying the two properties of the norm I used. So $0=\lim_{x\to 0} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x\to 0} g(x))$, since $f(a)=0$ iff $a=0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Martingalo Precisely as you say :)
Thanks for the patience, and for the help!

Comment: @Martingalo: Another question: consider a function $f$ continuous at 0 such that f(0)=0. Than we cannot conclude that $\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to0}g(x))$. In fact, we can't say that $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ exists (consider, for instance, a constant function $f$:$\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))$ exists for every function $g$).  So, isn't there something worth reviewing in your preceding argument?

Comment: @Matteo Well but if $f$ is constant and $f(0)=0$ then $f\equiv 0$ and hence it does not make sense to say $lim f() = f(lim)$, what is that? There is in fact no limit, $lim f = lim 0 =0$ (no limit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree that these definitions are different - they are just the same definition written in three different ways.  The first definition is what you will see in most textbooks; I would consider it to be the "standard" definition.  To parse the second definition, recall that a sequence $v_k$ of vectors in Euclidean space converges to $v$ if the sequence $|v_k - v|$ of real numbers converges to $0$ (this is nothing more than the definition of convergence in Euclidean space).

Finally, the third definition should read:
$$f(a + h) - f(a) - \lambda(h) = |h|r(h)$$
for some function $r(h)$ which converges to $0$ as $h \to 0$.  (Actually, some authors will write $\leq$ instead of $<$.)  In any event, you can just solve this equation for $r(h)$ to get:
$$r(h) = \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - \lambda(h)}{|h|} \to 0$$
which is exactly the second definition.

Comment: "Actually some authors will write $\leq$ instead of $<$." To what $<$ sign are you referring?

Comment: Sorry I meant "=" - some will write $f(a+h) - f(a) = \lambda(h) \leq |h|r(h)$.